# Microsoft Graph API (user/licenseDetails enpoint) - Subscription charge?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was recently building an api to match active directory and fetch their "users//licenseDetails" and service plans from azure ad via graph api.

I just recently discovered that some of their endpoints are paid per request.

How big of a trouble am I in?

I was testing data from 800 domain accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the details:

[image]

For more information regarding the pricing please check here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/graph-data-connect/